# When do we know "not to use comma" before "which"?

Tags: commas

To my knowledge, we do not put comma before *which* but I have seen some sentences putting comma before *which*.

i.e. I don't like stories which have unhappy endings.

i.e. The heavy use of automobiles in urban areas, which could lead to a serious air pollution problem in cities.

Why the former one doesn't have comma before *which* but the latter one does?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Comma Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/comma) by The Oxford Dictionaries, part of their [Punctuation Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/punctuation).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your second example isn't a grammatically correct sentence. It's a sentence fragment. There is no predicate. "The heavy use of automobiles in urban areas" needs to *do* something. To make it a sentence, just remove "which": *The heavy use of automobiles in urban areas could lead to a serious air pollution problem in cities.*

Comment: Where did you get the idea that "we do not put comma before which"?  That is an incorrect assumption.  Sometimes you can put commas before *which* and sometimes you shouldn't!  Also, you Q. may be more suited to our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/].

Answer (score 0):

"... which have unhappy endings" modifies "stories" and thus does not take a comma.

"... which could lead to a serious..." is a new clause (I think!) and takes a comma -- and avoids the possibility of it being incorrectly understood as modifying "use."

Comment: I think that's right, but just in the most ordinary interpretation.  If you wanted to say that **all** stories have unhappy endings, you'd need a comma.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your second sentence is ungrammatical. You need to add something else to it:

> The heavy use of automobiles in urban areas, which could lead to a serious air pollution problem in cities, *is prohibited.*

---

In US English, your first sentence would likely use *that*, not *which*:

> I don't like stories **that** have unhappy endings.

Or it could dispense with both words:

> I don't like stories *with* unhappy endings.

Only in UK English is it traditionally considered acceptable to use **which** with a restrictive clause if *that* would also work. So, in UK English, you may or may not see a comma before *which*. Either is acceptable, so long as the presence or lack of comma is acceptable. (I don't know enough about this UK styling to talk more about how the particular word is chosen.)

In US English, however, if *either* of the words sounds like it could work, then it's normally *that* without a comma or *which* with a comma.

Still, regardless of the word itself, the US and UK have the same general guideline: use a comma before a nonrestrictive clause but not before a restrictive clause.

---

There are situations where you would use [*which*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/which) without a comma, even in US English:

> ✘ I don't know **that** item to choose.
> → ✔ I don't know **which** item to choose.
>
> ✘ **That** of those houses do you live in?
> → ✔ **Which** of those houses do you live in?

Comment: It’s perfectly _acceptable_ to use _which_ non-restrictively in AmE as well – it’s just more _common_ in BrE. StoneyB (who is American) wrote an ELU blog post about it once, advocating for using _which_ more. (In your examples at the end, _which_ is an entirely different word, a relative determiner and interrogative pronoun, respectively. Since_that_ does not exist as a either of those at all, it stands to reason that _that_ is not an option there.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In my answer, I said that (in the US) *which* is normally nonrestrictive and *that* is normally restrictive. When I mentioned the UK, I said that *which* can also be used restrictively, which is not normally the case in the US. Also, in my additional comment, *which* is not a different word. It's the same word being used in a different *sense* or grammatical *role*.

Comment: Gah, that should have been _restrictively_, not _non-restrictively_ in my previous comment. My point was that though it’s more common in BrE, it’s not traditionally considered _unacceptable_ in AmE.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Got it. I've heard that it *is* unacceptable in US law specifically. (Even if that is domain specific.) And according to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/that-or-which) (with respect to the restrictive *which*), "this common British construction is not strictly incorrect in American English, but it is generally avoided, especially in formal writing."